# Is it possible to calculate gradient of layer within sequential model in Keras neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have a multi input Keras neural network where I want to calculate the gradient of the output with respect to one of the intermediate layers. The layer I chose is inside one of my sequential models that handles one of the two inputs to the model.

But when I try to calculate the gradient with respect to this layer I get `[None]` returned as the output. I am able to take the gradient for other layers such as the concatenate layer, but not any layers within my 2 branches. Is it possible for me to take the gradient of this layer given that it is within a sequential wrapper in my model?

Here is some code that shows what I'm trying to do.

```
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, concatenate
import keras.backend as K

# Init branch 1
branch1 = Sequential()
branch1.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(1000,)))
branch1.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))

# Init branch 2
branch2 = Sequential()
branch2.add(Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(500,)))
branch2.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))

branch1_input = Input(shape=(1000,))
branch1_out = branch1(branch1_input)

branch2_input = Input(shape=(500,))
branch2_out = branch2(branch2_input)

# Combine
x = concatenate([branch1_out, branch2_out])
out = Dense(1)(x)

# Create model
model = Model(inputs=[branch1_input, branch2_input], outputs=out)

layer = model.get_layer('sequential_1').get_layer('dense_2')
grads = K.gradients(model.output, layer.output)

print(grads) # prints out [None]
```